# Конфигурация hibernate без использования xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Каким образом возможно сконфигурировать EntityManager в Hibernate без использования persistence.xml? Может есть подход создания конфигурации через аннотации или напрямую в коде? Буду рад любой ссылке

Comment: а как вы собираетесь без конфигов полностью обойтись, даже для спринг бута конфиги нужны

Comment: Тот же SessionFactory можно использовать без конфигов, просто сконфигурировав все в коде. У меня проект запускается другим проектом из-за чего конфиги hibernate не может найти.

Comment: Но доступ к бд, драйвер к бд насколько мне известно заполняется только в конфиге

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
private static EntityManager entityManager;

public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
    return entityManagerFactory;
}

public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    if(entityManager != null) {
        entityManager.close();
    }
    if(entityManagerFactory != null) {
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}

public static void build(){
    entityManagerFactory = new HibernatePersistenceProvider().createContainerEntityManagerFactory(
            archiverPersistenceUnitInfo(),
            new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                    put(JPA_JDBC_DRIVER, JPA_JDBC_DRIVER);
                    put(JPA_JDBC_URL, JPA_JDBC_URL);
                    put(DIALECT, PostgreSQL95Dialect.class);
                    put(SHOW_SQL, true);
                    put(QUERY_STARTUP_CHECKING, false);
                    put(GENERATE_STATISTICS, false);
                    put(USE_REFLECTION_OPTIMIZER, false);
                    put(USE_SECOND_LEVEL_CACHE, false);
                    put(USE_QUERY_CACHE, false);
                    put(USE_STRUCTURED_CACHE, false);
                    put(STATEMENT_BATCH_SIZE, 20);
            }}
    );

    entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}

private static PersistenceUnitInfo archiverPersistenceUnitInfo() {
    return new PersistenceUnitInfo() {
        @Override
        public String getPersistenceUnitName() {
            return "YourPersistenceUnit";
        }

        @Override
        public String getPersistenceProviderClassName() {
            return "org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider";
        }

        @Override
        public PersistenceUnitTransactionType getTransactionType() {
            return PersistenceUnitTransactionType.RESOURCE_LOCAL;
        }

        @Override
        public DataSource getJtaDataSource() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public DataSource getNonJtaDataSource() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<String> getMappingFileNames() {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        @Override
        public List<URL> getJarFileUrls() {
            try {
                return Collections.list(this.getClass()
                        .getClassLoader()
                        .getResources(""));
            }catch(IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public URL getPersistenceUnitRootUrl() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<String> getManagedClassNames() {
            return entityClassNames();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean excludeUnlistedClasses() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public SharedCacheMode getSharedCacheMode() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ValidationMode getValidationMode() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Properties getProperties() {
            return hibernateProperties();
        }

        @Override
        public String getPersistenceXMLSchemaVersion() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ClassLoader getClassLoader() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void addTransformer(ClassTransformer transformer) {

        }

        @Override
        public ClassLoader getNewTempClassLoader() {
            return null;
        }
    };
}

private static Properties hibernateProperties(){
    final Properties properties = new Properties();

    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update" );
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver" );
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect" );
    properties.put("hibernate.connection.datasource", dataSource());

    return properties;
}

private static DataSource dataSource() {
    final PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
    dataSource.setDatabaseName("dbName");
    dataSource.setUser("user");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");
    return dataSource;
}

private static List<String> entityClassNames() {
    Class<?>[] entities = new Class<?>[] {
        YourEntity.class
    };
    return Arrays.stream(entities).map(Class::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

}